# Unable to connect to wireless network, Wireless card shows very low signal strength

Tags: networking, drivers, lubuntu, realtek-wireless

I have a laptop `hp 15-ac110tx`. I have a problem with Wireless card in Ubuntu 16.04(not working with 15.04 14.04 also). My laptop shows very weak wireless signals and always unable to connect to a network unit i am just next to the router. But it is working absolutely fine with windows. Right now i am 2 meters away from my router but still unable to connect, though some times it does but it keeps fluctuating.

My wireless card info:

```
13:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

Someone please help me.